# JavaScript: get date of the passing Sunday

Tags: javascript, date

Appreciate your help!

Is there a way to get the date of the passing Sunday?  For example, today is Jan 29, 2014, how to get date the passing Sunday(20140126)?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get today's date:

```
 var today = new Date();
```

and then scoot backwards by the current day of the week:

```
 today.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay());
```

Now if you do that on Sunday, the date doesn't change. You'd have to add a special case if you wanted to go back to the previous Sunday.

Comment: If today is the one of the first days in the month, will it work?

Comment: @user3228457 yes - the JavaScript Date object code will do the "right thing".

Comment: Thank you Pointy.  Now I got the correct Date (for example, Sun Jan 26 2014 07:59:37 GMT-0800 (PST)), is there an easy way to change to "20140126"?

Comment: @user3228457 the Date APIs `getFullYear()`, `getDate()`, and `getMonth()` give you the values. You just have to glue them together as strings. Don't forget that `getMonth()` returns 0 ... 11, not 1 ... 12.